Find all files matching given path format with datetime
I'm looking to identify all files whose path matches a given format (for example %Y/%j/data_%d.txt) and retrieve the associated date.
A simple solution is to use strptime, but this doesn't work if a 'format code' appears twice in the format (e.g. %Y/%j/data_%Y%m%d.txt). This is a strptime limitation linked to the use of re, which has long been documented (https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/48680).
Do you have any idea how I can deal with this?
I've long used this (somewhat complicated) piece of code to handle cases where a 'format code' appears twice but in two different levels of the tree (folder, file ...):
def get_path(path_format: List[str], path: str = "") -> List[str]:
    """ return all path matching the given pattern with datetime format (%Y, %m etc...) handled

    :param path_format: List of directories to explore, ex: ['test', '%Y', '%Y%m', 'data_%Y%m%d.txt']
    :param path: directory to explore
    :return: List of all matching path
    """
    if len(path_format) == 0:
        return [path]
    current_format = path_format[0]
    if '%' in current_format:
        out = []
        current_content = os.listdir(path)
        for content in current_content:
            try:
                datetime.datetime.strptime(content, current_format)
            except ValueError:
                continue
            out += get_path(path_format[1:], os.path.join(path, content))
        return out
    else:
        path = os.path.join(path, current_format)
        if os.path.exists(path):
            return get_path(path_format[1:], path)
        else:
            return []

$ tree data/2017/
data/2017/
├── 001
│   └── data_20170101.txt
└── 100
    └── data_20170407.txt

>>> p = 'data/%Y/%j/data_%Y%m%d.txt'
>>> p = p.split('/')
>>> get_path(p)
['data/2017/100/data_20170407.txt', 'data/2017/001/data_20170101.txt']

However, I need to manage new data where the 'code format' appears twice in the same folder or file name (for example: data/%Y/%j/data_%Y%m%dT0000_%Y%m%dT9000.txt).
Edit: I found a workaround during the weekend, the solution is not ideal but will do the job until I find a better one. I just split the file name in multiple parts using a separator character (in my case _). Here is the code:
def merge_two_dates(d1, d2):
    return d1.replace(year=max(d1.year, d2.year),
                      month=max(d1.month, d2.month),
                      day=max(d1.day, d2.day),
                      hour=max(d1.hour, d2.hour),
                      minute=max(d1.minute, d2.minute),
                      second=max(d1.second, d2.second),
                      microsecond=max(d1.microsecond, d2.microsecond))


def merge_dates(dates):
    date = datetime.datetime.min
    for d in dates:
        date = merge_two_dates(d, date)
    return date


def dates_from_path_rec(path_format: List[str], split_c: str = "", path: str = "") -> List[datetime.datetime]:
    """ return all path matching the given pattern with datetime format (%Y, %m etc...) handled

    :param path_format: List of directories to explore, ex: ['test', '%Y', '%Y%m', 'data_%Y%m%d.txt']
    :param split_c: If two dates are in the same directory / file name, split_c will be used to split this name.
    :param path: directory to explore
    :return: List of date of all matching path
    """
    if len(path_format) == 0:
        return [datetime.datetime.min]
    current_format = path_format[0]

    if '%' in current_format:
        split_format = current_format.split(split_c) if len(split_c) > 0 else [current_format]

        out = []
        current_content = os.listdir(path)
        for content in current_content:
            split_content = content.split(split_c) if len(split_c) > 0 else [content]
            if len(split_format) != len(split_content):
                continue

            try:
                dates = [datetime.datetime.strptime(sc, sf)
                         for sc, sf in zip(split_content, split_format) if '%' in sf]
            except ValueError:
                continue

            date = merge_dates(dates)
            if date.strftime(current_format) != content:
                continue

            out += [merge_two_dates(date, d)
                    for d in dates_from_path_rec(path_format[1:], split_c, os.path.join(path, content))]
        return out
    else:
        path = os.path.join(path, current_format)
        if os.path.exists(path):
            return dates_from_path_rec(path_format[1:], split_c, path)
        else:
            return []


I've finally found a solution to my problem.
The regex package extends the capabilities of the re library, and in particular handles cases of group name redefinition. By copying and modifying the _strptime.py file from python, I can obtain a function that accepts formats with group name redefinition.
My custome strptime.py file (copy of _strptime.py):
from regex import compile as regex_compile

...

class TimeRE(dict):
    ...

    def compile(self, format):
        """Return a compiled re object for the format string."""
        return regex_compile(self.pattern(format), IGNORECASE)

...

def str_to_time(data_string, format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"):
    """Return a time struct based on the input string and the
    format string."""
    tt = _strptime(data_string, format)[0]
    return time.struct_time(tt[:time._STRUCT_TM_ITEMS])


def str_to_cls(cls, data_string, format="%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y"):
    """Return a class cls instance based on the input string and the
    format string."""
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
    tzname, gmtoff = tt[-2:]
    args = tt[:6] + (fraction,)
    if gmtoff is not None:
        tzdelta = datetime_timedelta(seconds=gmtoff, microseconds=gmtoff_fraction)
        if tzname:
            tz = datetime_timezone(tzdelta, tzname)
        else:
            tz = datetime_timezone(tzdelta)
        args += (tz,)

    return cls(*args)

I can then use these functions to rewrite my function date_from_path():
import strptime

def matching_paths(path_format: List[str], path: str = "") -> List[str]:
    """ return all path matching the given pattern with datetime format (%Y, %m etc...) handled

    :param path_format: List of directories to explore, ex: ['test', '%Y', '%Y%m', 'data_%Y%m%d.txt']
    :param path: directory to explore
    :return: List of date of all matching path
    """
    if len(path_format) == 0:
        return [path]
    current_format = path_format[0]

    if '%' in current_format:
        out = []
        current_content = os.listdir(path)
        for content in current_content:
            try:
                strptime.str_to_time(content, current_format)
            except ValueError:
                continue
            out += matching_paths(path_format[1:], os.path.join(path, content))
        return out
    else:
        path = os.path.join(path, current_format)
        if os.path.exists(path):
            return matching_paths(path_format[1:], path)
        else:
            return []


def dates_from_path(fmt: str) -> Set[datetime.datetime]:
    """ Return all date from file matching fmt
    :param fmt: input path to explore to find input_object, can contain %Y, %m, %d ...
    :return: 
    """
    fmt = os.path.normpath(fmt)

    # set of dates (remove redundancy)
    dates = matching_paths(fmt.split(os.sep))
    dates = [strptime.str_to_cls(datetime.datetime, d, fmt) for d in dates]
    dates = set(dates)

    # assert each date is working, avoid potential problem that could have occurred during recurrence
    dates = set([date for date in dates if os.path.exists(date.strftime(fmt))])
    return dates

